# Importing Contacts from dotProject

Tags: contacts

I have a bazoodle of contacts in a dotProject csv file.  I'd really like to import these into U1 (maybe via Evolution).

I can tell which fields are what (e.g., what's last name, etc.) in the dotProject file, but I don't know how to tell, e.g., Evolution what's what so I can import them.

Has anyone done this, or know how?  I've looked around to no avail!

Thanks

Comment: For the .csv file layout that Evolution expects, there's an entry in the German ubuntuusers Wiki http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Evolution#Datenmigration (subsection "Beliebige Adressdaten importieren"; first line in the code display). You could try to re-arrange your .csv file in that order -- e.g. using OpenOffice Calc -- , and add that first line on top of your .csv.

Comment: @BernhardReiter Please answer the question

Comment: @AmithKK You mean by just pasting my comment, or are you asking for something more to-the-point?

Comment: If you can, please improve it. If not, just answer it :D

Answer (score 0):

For the .csv file layout that Evolution expects, there's an entry in the [German ubuntuusers Wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Evolution#Datenmigration) (subsection "Beliebige Adressdaten importieren"; first line in the code display):

```
"First Name","Last Name","id","NickName","E-mail Address","E-mail 2 Address","E-mail 3 Address","E-mail 4 Address","Wants HTML","Business Phone","Home Phone","Business Fax","Pager","Mobile Phone","Home Street","Home Street 2","Home City","Home State","Home Postal Code","Home Country","Business Street","Business Street 2","Business City","Business State","Business Postal Code","Business Country","Job Title","Office","Company","Web Page","Cal uri","Birth Year","Birth Month","Birth Day","Notes"
```

You could try to re-arrange your .csv file in that order -- e.g. using (OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice) Calc -- , and add that as first line on top of your .csv.